# Bug where clip speed is faster than all other clips from the same source video

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, video-sequence-editor, edit-mode, video

I believe I am encountering a bug. I took two takes of a video I made and edited the video together using mostly just one of those takes with only soft cuts. The format is AVCHD 1080p30. I also recorded audio on a blue yetti microphone and synced everything up. In the preview screen everything plays as I would expect it to. When I render the video however (Format MPEG-4, codec H.246, audio FLAC) there is one clip right in the middle where the video seems to go at roughly double time the audio. Also the clip plays more frames than I had clipped. It is as if it got the start and end time right, but not the speed of the video. It is only one clip that is affected in this way, and all other clips from the same exact source are unaffected. When I try to put an effect on that particular clip to slow it down suddenly the preview window does think that the clip is faster than it should be and I needed to slow it down to .4 of the original speed, but when I render it it goes back to it's original 2.5 times faster. Can someone help me figure out what is happening? Please let me know if I should be providing more information. I tried to provide what I thought might be relevant but recognize that a lot of things could be causing trouble.

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps that video portion (for whatever reason) had lagged a little, and Blender started squishing the video (matching one frame per frame)?

Comment: Would I need to reimport the clip in order to avoid lag or could I check some of the clip properties to undo some sort of lag effect?